# How to reduce loading time for ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync() on Expo Go for iOS videos?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

When I use `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync(`) to select an iOS video for Expo Go, the returned promise is fulfilled after several seconds of waiting. I'm wondering if there's any way to reduce the wait time for `launchImageLibraryAsync` to return the target video.

A potential solution I've attempted to look into is a "loading indicator" for `launchImageLibraryAsync`. If such a feature existed, I could leverage it to see how much longer I would need to wait for `launchImageLibraryAsync` to finish.

I tried researching Expo's docs regarding ImagePicker at https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickeroptions. However, I did not come across any information that was helpful.

Comment: Setting `preferredAssetRepresentationMode` to ` ImagePicker.UIImagePickerPreferredAssetRepresentationMode.Current` resolved this issue for me